# Displaying the control name that failed event validation in ASP.Net postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

In my application, I am receiving event validation failure, after the upgrade to VS 2010. Weird thing is this kind of validation failure occurs in some of the machines, and in some of them everything works smoothly.

I am unable to find out the control which is failing the post back check. Is there any way to identify the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __EVENTTARGET form field will identify which control was the intended target for the post back. The __EVENTARGUMENT field contains the parameter that was posted to that particular control.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out on Monday, and hopefully solve my issues.

Comment: Well that was fruitless. Turns out there is no postback call. Application is using submit button instead. So, now I am back to square one.